# Rock paper scissors in C# using more efficient choice comparison

Tags: c#, object-oriented, classes

I decided to create a rock, paper, scissors game in C#.

I realised early on that standard if-else evaluation in rock-paper-scissors would take up a lot of code. So I decided to use more efficient choice comparison in my game as you will see below.

Is this an efficient choice comparison? Or should I stick to 'if else'. How could I improve this code? Maybe I am not doing something right?

I am looking for any sort of feedback.

```
namespace RockPaperScissors
{
    public class Weapon
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string WeakTo { get; set; }
        public string StrongTo { get; set; }
    }
    public static class AvailableOptions
    {
        public static Weapon[] Options => new Weapon[]
        {
             new Weapon()
             {
                 Name = "Rock",
                 WeakTo = "Paper",
                 StrongTo = "Scissors"
             },
             new Weapon()
             {
                Name = "Paper",
                WeakTo = "Scissors",
                StrongTo = "Rock"
             },
             new Weapon()
             {
                Name = "Scissors",
                WeakTo = "Rock",
                StrongTo = "Paper"
             },
        };
    }
    public class RockPaperScissors
    {
        public string[] PossibleValues = new string[] { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
        public int Rounds { get; set; }
        public void StartGame()
        {
            int roundsCompleted = 0;

            while (Rounds > roundsCompleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Rock");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Paper");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Scissors");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Shoot!");

                Ask();

                roundsCompleted++;
            }
        }
        private void Ask()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            Random rnd = new Random();

            string consoleInput = PossibleValues[rnd.Next(0, PossibleValues.Length)];

            Console.WriteLine(consoleInput);

            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

            Evaluate(consoleInput, input);
        }
        private void Evaluate(string ConsoleInput, string UserInput)
        {
            foreach (Weapon w in AvailableOptions.Options)
            {
                switch (UserInput)
                {
                    case var _ when UserInput.Trim().ToLower() == w.Name.Trim().ToLower():
                        switch (w)
                        {
                            case var _ when (w.StrongTo == ConsoleInput):
                                Console.WriteLine("You won"); 
                                break;

                            case var _  when (w.WeakTo == ConsoleInput):
                                Console.WriteLine("You lost");
                                break;

                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("Tie");
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.Clear();
        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                RockPaperScissors rockPaperScissors = new RockPaperScissors()
                {
                    Rounds = 5, 
                };
                rockPaperScissors.StartGame();

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you CodeReview StackExchange,

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");` can be changed to `Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));`. Also `switch-case` of one `case` statement can be changed to simple `if`. Two more things: you may use `enum` instead of `string` for weapon type, and don't create `new Random()` each round, create it once.